# How Can I sum all digits in a number using loop?

Tags: c#

when I enter 1 for n
and 1111 for lines
the sum must be 1+1+1+1=4 but the output is 1.

THIS IS THE QUESTION...

you will get a (n) then (n) lines as an input, In each line there are some numbers (we don’t know how many they are) and you must print (n) lines, In the i-th line print the sum of numbers in the i-th line.

```
using System;

namespace prom2
{
    class Program
    {
            
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int lines=0, sum = 0;

            Console.Write("Enter a number of lines ");
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 1; i <= n&n>0&1000>n; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter line " + i + " numbers");
                lines = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                lines = lines / 10;

                sum += lines % 10;
                             
                Console.WriteLine("sum is " + sum);

            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I need to ask user for n of lines then sum all digits in a line

Comment: To start, you need `&&` instead of just `&` in the conditional expression. Going a little further, you need an additional loop inside the `for`  loop to run while the lines value is greater than 0.

Comment: Are you saying you need to sum all individual digits? So if user enters `12` and then `34` the sum would be `10`?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, I'd soften "need" to a suggestion, since bitwise `&` will work just fine for all intents and purposes, but is sometimes less efficient.

Comment: Personally I would move the test on "n" to a loop around that ReadLine, not as exit condition in a for loop

Comment: Can you tell *us* "what is wrong"? What is the issue you see, including any error messages (as [edit] to your post)

Comment: Try stepping through your code in the debugger, and notice what happens to "lines" and "sum"

Comment: To simplify the confirmation.  You want a user to put a value > 0, less than 1000. You want to sum all numbers.  So ex: if 3 is entered, the numbers are 1, 2 & 3 resulting in 6.  If 8 is entered, 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8 = 36?  Or looking for something else

Comment: I think you're missing an inner loop that consumes all the digits of the number. Right now youre only adding the second-to-last-number to the sum.If the user enters 123, 2 is added to the sum

Comment: I have just edited the question

Comment: Please give a sample input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Because `Console.ReadLine` returns a `string`, and it's possible to treat a `string` as if it's an array of `char`s (where `char` represents a single character), you can have a method like this to calculate the sum of all the digits in a single line:

```
private int SumTheDigits(string line)
{
    var sum = 0;
    foreach (var character in line)
    {
        sum += int.Parse(character.ToString());
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Please note this method contains no validation - ideally you should validate that `line` is purely numeric, otherwise `int.Parse` will throw an exception, although the same is true of the code you provided too.

If you want to work with multiple lines of console input, just call this method from within another loop which solicits / works through those lines of console input.

## Edit

My answer doesn't answer all of your question, it only answers the part which asks how to calculate the sum of the digits in a numeric string, and it does work, to the extent that it correctly does what it says on the tin.

Here's all the code I wrote to validate the answer before posting the original answer (I wrote it as a xUnit unit test rather than a console application, but that doesn't change the fact that the code I shared works):

```
using System;
using Xunit;

namespace StackOverflow71442136SumDigits
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Theory]
        [InlineData("1", 1)]
        [InlineData("12", 3)]
        [InlineData("23", 5)]
        [InlineData("1234", 10)]
        [InlineData("123456789", 45)]
        public void Test1(string line, int expectedSum)
        {
            var actualSum = this.SumTheDigits(line);
            Assert.Equal(expectedSum, actualSum);
        }

        private int SumTheDigits(string line)
        {
            var sum = 0;
            foreach (var character in line)
            {
                sum += int.Parse(character.ToString());
            }

            return sum;
        }
    }
}
```

You might want to read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Are you getting a compiler error when trying to include it in your code? Is it returning different results to what you're expecting, if so please provide inputs and expected/actual outputs.

Comment: Added to the answer to clarify exactly what I was answering. This looks like a homework question. We can help but we're not going to do your homework for you. It's up to you to work out how to make use of (or improve) the code snippet I've given you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int input;
            bool times = true;
            List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
            while (times)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter number: ");
                var num = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input);//tryparse will output a bool into num and set input to a int
                if (num)
                {
                    numbers.Add(input);//only integers will be added to list
                }
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Another? Y or N");//ask if they want to sum more numbers
                var yesno = Console.ReadLine();//get answer from user
                if (yesno.ToUpper().Trim() != "Y")//if N or anything else
                {
                    //assume no
                    times = false;
                }
                Console.Clear();
            }

            var sum = numbers.Sum();
            Console.WriteLine("Sum : " + sum.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();//just to pause screen
        }
```